# Writing a program to interact with other program

Tags: java, windows-8

Is there any way to write a program with Java on Windows,that can fill out data prompts from another program?
Basically automate the interaction with another program which would otherwise have to be done using mouse & keyboard?

Comment: Yes, you can try using Robot class http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke

Comment: @normad The use of the words *another program* is too broad. You need to narrow it down to built in programs on windows or programs written in Java.

Comment: +1 with Pshemo, robot is a solution but robot goes on to use mouse and keyboard. The single difference is that it's robot which does it instead of the human user.
So, to use it, you must be sure that the program which will receive input, stays in front of the screen.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29 **Written in Java**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html):
This class supports automatic operations with mouse and keyboard
http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke